Ready-made tool for satellite maneuver detection
I am looking for a tool to detect satellite maneuvers from TLE data. The tool should be easy-to- apply (not my field at all) to many satellites, i.e., not rely on visual inspection or similar.
Shorten et al. (2024) (see below) provides a nice overview of methods. However, so far, I haven't found any of those authors providing the tools/programs they use online. Is this not commen in this literature? Given that I don't have strong familiarity with this subject matter, there is no big hope that I can replicate the methods in those papers myself.
Thank you for any tips or ideas.
D.P. Shorten, M. Humphries, J. Maclean et al., Optimal proposal particle filters for detecting anomalies and manoeuvres from two line element data, Acta Astronautica (2024) (also arXiv)

This is an interesting question.  As a hack (I have no specialized knowledge in this topic), I wonder if given two consecutive TLEs, and then computing/propagating each to both TLE epochs and evaluating the differences in position/velocity, perhaps a threshold could be set to determine the likelihood of a maneuver between the two epoch times.
